# Appveyor release artifact not detected

Tags: appveyor

I'm trying to release new version on a test projet but my artifact is not recognised.

```
Discovering tests...OK
Deploying using GitHub provider
Creating "a2" release for repository "Phonations/TravisTest" tag "a2" commit "44d044aa7708508f016dfef67fbdd82f08642f8d"...OK
No artifacts were published. Make sure you have specified correct artifacts filter.
Build success
```

(full output available [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/MartinDelille/travistest/build/1.0.151))

I checked the artifact *artifact.txt* is present as you can see when performing the *dir* command in the build output.
It is specified [here](https://github.com/Phonations/TravisTest/blob/44d044aa7708508f016dfef67fbdd82f08642f8d/appveyor.yml#L27)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup artifacts packaging in `appveyor.yml`. For that file in your project this would be:

```
artifacts:
- path: artifact.txt
```